# internal implementation of DataTransfer.effectAllowed in firefox and chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm currently studying the HTML5 drag and drop API on MDN and I'm interested in learning a bit more about how [DataTransfer.effectAllowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/effectAllowed)
 is implemented in firefox and chrome browser.

Because the source code for both browsers are huge and it is a difficult task for someone unfamiliar with the source code to find exact what they are looking for, so I was just wondering whether anyone can share their experience/strategy in searching through their source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about Chrome, but I'll try with Mozilla Firefox. Even though it's huge, the Firefox codebase is searchable using two different engines: [Searchfox](https://searchfox.org/) and [DXR](http://dxr.mozilla.org/). Both are great and have different pros/cons.

Searchfox:

- it's fast;
- it's easy to follow the code by looking up symbols/implementations and keep digging through the code from there.

DXR:

- is much more flexible;
- doesn't render RST files automatically (that's a pro to me :D).

Now, to your question, let's look up `DataTranfer.effectAllowed` using searchfox.

1. In the searchbox on the left, write `effectAllowed".
2. This gives a bunch of stuff, JS and C++. The second result comes from `dom/events/DataTransfer.h`, which might be what you're looking for.
3. Let's restrict the search to `.cpp` files by writing `*.cpp` in the box on the top right.
4. The second result will be from `dom/events/DataTransfer.cpp` which is exactly where the implementation lives. See [here](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/8f06c1b9a080b84435a2906e420fe102e1ed780b/dom/events/DataTransfer.cpp#128).

From there, depending on what you're looking for, you can keep investigating. I hope this helps :)

**Update: steps for searching Chromium's source**

Turns out Chromium has a similar [service](https://cs.chromium.org/) for searching through the code base. The steps are quite similar as well!

1. Go to https://cs.chromium.org/ .
2. Write `EffectAllowed` in the searchbox at the center of the page.
3. You'll be presented with a drop down with some results. Pick `setEffectAllowed (in blink::DataTransfer)`, the one with the `.cc` implementation file.
4. Browse to [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/clipboard/data_transfer.cc?q=EffectAllowed&sq=package:chromium&l=259) and have fun!

Comment: thanks @Dexter, for listing out the steps you took to find what is needed. Learning how it is done will definitely help me a lot in the future, when i encounter similar problems :) thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! I've Just updated my answer with how to search Chromium's source code.